# Only first page of Angular SPA is indexed by Google

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, angular.js

I am trying to get all pages of my site indexed by Google but only the first page is.
As mentioned in the title, it is an Angular (5) SPA.

When I run this query: `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://ecologicalprice.org`, the result is this:

[image: Google search results screenshot]

Seems like only`https://ecologicalprice.org/` was crawled and added to index.

I did the following:

- Used html5mode for the URLs (made sure to remove the `#` sign in the URLs)
- Ran [Fetch As Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) to make sure Google was able to crawl my pages correctly, and requested that it crawled the pages above
- Added a sitemap.txt file containing the pages above:

> ```
> https://ecologicalprice.org/prices/home?country=US&currency=AUTO
> https://ecologicalprice.org/prices/summary?country=US&currency=AUTO
> https://ecologicalprice.org/prices/details?country=US&currency=AUTO
> https://ecologicalprice.org/prices/contact?country=US&currency=AUTO
> ```

All of the above was done more than a week ago (March 24th, 2018, it is now March 31st, 2018). I saw Google crawled my site again soon after I asked it to:[image]

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

2 months later, I see a couple of new pages showing up:
[image]

So I think that proves that there is nothing wrong with my (static) setup, and that it's just that Google chooses what it wants to crawl. Maybe depends on the visibility of the page online (incoming links...), maybe depends on load time,...

I'll try to update the page if more pages show up in the search results.

Comment: Usually it is more of "chooses what it wants to index."  Google crawls a ton of pages without including them in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Right now all pages in my site have the same title. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413969/google-bot-cannot-fetch-angularjs-site-in-html5-mode), I'm adding a different title for each page, might work.

edit 2018/04/18: didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues that you're likely having is that your pages have very little html content.

It seems that you are rendering the content with javascript. When I test out your site in Mobile Friendly Test, Google shows that it can render your page. But it's possible that Googlebot may not be seeing it the same way perhaps. Googlebot has been known to have trouble with javascript rendering sometimes. It's possible that this is what may be causing your issue.

Googlebot may be able to see the content on your pages, but because it seems that all of your links are generated through javascript, it's possible that Google is having trouble reading your links and isn't crawling them.

I quickly browsed your javascript and see that you're using all of these base hrefs in them, and that it doesn't seem that your links are easily viewable. Your javascript is quite complex. And so I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that Google may not be able to crawl them because of it.

If there is a way that you can render the pages in full HTML this might substantially help you. You can also submit a sitemaps.xml file to Google in search console which can help Google discover your pages.

Comment: It can definitely index my first page so I don't see why it could not index the others? As I said in my question, I did submit a `sitemap.txt` file.